# How to append values to the html div ids using j Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working in an application where i am have to get dynamic values from database and have to dynamically append them to my html divs.To be more clear i have 4 labels which also have 4 divs is,now what i have to do, i have to append 4 values which i will get dynamically from database to that 4 divs .I am posting my code here what i have done  so far ,somebody please help

This is my html section where i have 4 divs

```
<div id="primaryLabel">
<table id="personalInformation">
        <tr>                
            <th>Address 1<span style='color: #FF0000; display: inline;'>*</span></th>   
            <td><label for="address1" id="address1ForLabel" ><%=address1 %></label></td>
            <td><a href="#" onclick="open_new();"><img style="border:0;" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/edit.png" title="Click to edit"></a> </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>                
            <th>Address 2<span style='color: #FF0000; display: inline;'>*</span></th>   
            <td><label for="address2" id="address2ForLabel"><%=address2 %></label></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <th>City<span style='color: #FF0000; display: inline;'>*</span></th>
            <td><label for="city" id="cityForLabel"><%=city %></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Primary Phone<span style='color: #FF0000; display: inline;'>*</span></th>
            <td><label for="primary phone" id="primaryPhoneForLabel"><%=primaryPhone %></label></td>
        </tr>       
</table>
</div>
```

This is my javascript/jQuery end where i am getting four values.Now i want to append them dynamically every time .Posting my code here

```
 jQuery.getJSON(url+"&address1="+address1+"&address2="+address2+"&country="+country+"&state="+state+"&city="+city+"&zip="+zip+"&skypeId="+skypeId+"&twitter="+twitter+"&primaryPhone="+primaryPhone+"&secondaryPhone="+secondaryPhone+"&type="+type, function(data) {

        $( "div.success" ).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 2500 ).fadeOut( 400 );

        for(var z=0; z<data.applicationArray.length;z++){

            applicationArray = data.applicationArray[z].split("$$##$$##");

            address1 = applicationArray[0];
            address2 = applicationArray[1];
            city = applicationArray[2];
            primaryPhone = applicationArray[3];

        }
        alert(address1+":"+address2+":"+city+":"+primaryPhone);
```

address1 ,address2,city,primaryPhone  are those parameters .What i have tried i have done

```
        $('#address1ForLabel').html(address1);
        $('#address1ForLabe2').append(address2);
        $('#cityForLabel').html(city);
        $('#primaryPhoneForLabel').html(primaryPhone);
```

But this  is not working for me.Please someone help me out of this.

Comment: did your variable are visible there, put console and see whether you are getting that value or not

Comment: $('#address1ForLabe2').data(address2); not working

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV   address1ForLabe2   is the div id

Comment: did you check the adress1,2.. fields have values everytime ??

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV yes they have the previous values thats why i am trying to replace them with the new values

Comment: are you trying replace or append 
?? both are different . actually what did you want append or replace ? also i can't find any div with id "address1ForLabel" in your code where is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to append your value in an extra `<div>`:

```
$('#address1ForLabel').append('<div>'address1'</div>');
```

or to replace the original `<label>`:

```
$('#address1ForLabel').replaceWith("<label for="address1" id="address1ForLabel" >" address1 "</label>")
```

Comment: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable error showing

Answer (score 0):

The solution was

```
        $('#address1ForLabel').text(address1);
        $('#address2ForLabel').text(address2);
        $('#cityForLabel').text(city);
        $('#primaryPhoneForLabel').text(primaryPhone);
```

Comment: this will replace the old data. you are asking for append